# ReadyApi - 403 Forbidden, 200 Postman code

Tags: soapui, rest-client, ready-api

I have a problem with the service I want to call in readyApi. The same service returns status 200 in Postman, while in ReadyApi I get status 403.
Has anyone had a similar problem? Only thing I found is there is a problem with the Header, but nothing specific.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@danio900409
can you compare the Raw Request from ReadyAPI with that from Postman? Anything different?

Are you running Postman Web or Desktop? Wondering if there are any network/firewall restrictions allow requests from Postman Web, but not where you are running ReadyAPI tests from.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the Raw request in ReadyAPI with the request in the Postman console.

There you can find what exactly was sent to the API server.

Since you are receiving HTTP 403, I assume you are using either different credentials or accessing another resource (with different authorization).

Answer (score 0):

adding on to the previous response. It's hard to identify the actual cause of this issue, but I would assume that whats going on is that your request has some kind of authentication that is set up in Postman but not in ReadyAPI. Would recommend checking out the [documentation on setting up Authentication in ReadyAPI](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/requests/auth/index.html).

I've worked with a few teams in the past who had similar issues, and they were pretty easy to spot if they were missing some kind of authentication by comparing the headers in the request. Creating an auth profile will add the appropriate headers into your request, but you can also add in custom headers if there is one missing on the ReadyAPI side of things.